# create project with compass/sass

Tags: ruby, command-line, sass, compass-sass

I'm having a problem getting started with compass/sass. I eventually managed to install compass, although I had to google around because the instructions on the compass website didn't work for me. 
Next step was to create a project. I thought this would be simple enough by typing:

```
$ compass create path/to/project --using blueprint/basic --sass-dir=sass --css-dir=css
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work. The first thing to fail was that it told me that --using was not a recognised command (even though that is exactly what it tells you to type in the compass installation instructions). So, I tried creating the project taking away all three of the additional options.
This did create a project, although not in the place I specified. Rather than placing it in path/to/project it created the files and directories straight into my home folder ie /Users/me/

I must be doing something wrong, I can't believe that a tool designed to save time and make life easier could be so difficult to get up and running. I'm not great at using the command line, but I am able to follow instructions!

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your running compass v0.8, please upgrade to v0.10 and that command will work.

Comment: This has always bothered me: `0.1 == 0.10` but `v0.1 != v0.10`.

Comment: yep, seems to have done the trick. Thanks! I don't know if it makes a difference, but on the compass website the installation instructions say to type:   gem install compass . This didn't work for me. Instead I used sudo install compass . As someone who doesn't really understand the command line and is reliant on instructions I thought I'd mention it!